# Laravel 5: Middleware don't work as expected

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing, laravel-middleware

I have a problem in my middleware.

Created custom middleware: php artisan AuthNew

[image]

Inside my AuthNew:

[image]

Inside my routes.php:
[image]

The problem is when I login it always redirect me to /account. Even if I do /logout thing it will still redirect me to /account. What I expect to happen is when I successfully login. All account routes will only routes if user is authenticated. and if not will redirect me to login page. And will not anymore access the /account link. vice versa with login. (if authenticated can't access the login page) Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

You apply your middleware to all routes in that route group, including **/postLogin**. Route middleware is run before controller is executed. When you try to login you are recognized as guest and therefore redirected to /account before /postLogin is executed. Declare **/postLogin** route outside that group so that middleware is not applied.